# Docker: Mounted directory doesn't have files

Tags: docker

I'm trying to mount a directory along with all of it's file contents. But it seems to only mount the directory without the contents:

```
> ls ~/test_dir
testfile

> docker run -it --rm --entrypoint bash -v ~/test_dir/:/test_dir:ro my_image:latest
bash-4.2# cd test_dir
bash-4.2# ls -a
.  ..
bash-4.2#
```

I'm using Oracle Linux 7.9 terminal
Docker version 20.10.9

Comment: I don't think it should be a problem, but just to weed out problems between Oracle and your image, can you run `docker run -it --rm --entrypoint sh -v ~/test_dir/:/test_dir:ro busybox` and `cd` into the test_dir folder from a busybox image? I just ran this locally and I was able to view the contents of `~/test_dir`.

Comment: Same result. Directory is there but no files in it.
I'm using WSL also, idk if that matters.

@RobertStefanic

Comment: Does the image have some `WORKDIR` other than `/` set?  If you `docker run --rm --entrypoint /bin/ls my_image /test_dir` pointing explicitly at the filesystem root, do you see it?  (This gets less awkward the image doesn't force you to override `--entrypoint`.)

Comment: Ok so `docker run --rm -v ~/test_dir:/test_dir:ro --entrypoint /bin/ls airef_train_and_serve:0.1.0 /test_dir`

yields the result 'testfile' which was correct. 

However, After removing testfile from ~/test_dir, and adding other contents. The same docker command still yields testfile (despite the actual testfile being removed from ~/test_dir and other files being added) Any ideas? @DavidMaze

Note: If I do a typo such as `~/test_dirrrr:test_dir:ro`, no results will be yielded from the `ls`